# Parameters of Ellipsoid dependent of other variables in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I'm very new to Mathematica;

I'm trying to use it to display a Manipulate of an Ellipsoid that contains the parameters dependent of other variables.

For example, my ellipsoid equation `(x^2/j + y^2/k + z^2/l = 1)` has the values of j, k, and z dependent of other parameters (a,b,c...), which are the parameters that I'd like to change in the Manipulate.

It is below the simple algorithm that I tried to create, but there are some errors that I could not fix.

```
Manipulate[

j:= a + b + c;

k:= d - e + g;

l:= h + i;

Graphics3D[
  Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {j, k, l}], {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, 
   j, k, l}, PlotRange -> 2], {a, 1, 2}, {b,1, 2}, {c, 1, 
  2}, {d, 1, 2}, {e, 1, 2}, {f, 1, 2}, {g, 1, 2}, {h, 1, 
  2}, {i, 1, 2}]
```

Sorry about this question, 
Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why have so many quantities been introduced, when `j`, `k`, and `l` are sufficient?

Comment: I meant that my values of  j, k, and l are functions of other variables (a, b, c ,d ,e ...), and these variables (a, b, c) that I would like to change; consequently, it will change the values of j, k and l.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 j = a + b + c;
 k = d - e + g;
 l = h + i;
 Graphics3D[
  Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {j, k, l}],
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-3, 3}, {-4, 4}},
  Axes -> True],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{a, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{b, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{c, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{d, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{e, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}], 
    Control[{{f, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{g, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{h, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{i, 2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}}]]
```

[image]